Simulate a Brownian motion by exponential time stepping
Let $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Brownian motion. We can simulate a path of $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ using the Euler-Maruyama discretization scheme. Now, in the paper Efficient Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations Using Exponential Timestepping a different time-discretization is proposed, where the timesteps are drawn from an exponential distribution (say with parameter $\alpha>0$), which is independent of the Brownian motion.
While it's clear to me that when $T\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\alpha)$ is independent of $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$, then $B_T$ has density $$\mathbb R\ni x\mapsto\frac\alpha2 e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}x}\tag1$$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure, I don't get how I turn this into a practical algorithm.
First of all, from their eq. (5), it seems like they agree with my claim about the density $(1)$ above. But then, in their eq. (18), they say that the density of $B_{t+T}-B_t$ would be $$\mathbb R\ni x\mapsto\frac\nu2e^{-\nu|x|}\tag2$$ instead; where $\nu:=\sqrt{2\alpha}$. Inserting $t=0$ clearly yields a contradiction to the previous result (due to the $|\;\cdot\;|$ now occurring).
Then, when it comes to simulation, we start our simulation at $B_0=0$ and then need to sample from $B_{T_1}$, where $T_1:=T$. If $(2)$ would be the density, then this should be a Laplace distribution. If $(1)$ is the distribution, I don't know ...
In any case, we now can use that $$B^{(1)}_t:=B_{T_1+t}-B_{T_1}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is again a Brownian motion. Using that, we see that sampling of the next increment $B_{T_1+T_2}=B^{(1)}_{T_2}$ can be done the same way we sampled $B_{T_1}$.
Intermediate question: The only problem with that is that we don't get the actual time steps $T_i$ if we directly draw $B_{T_i}$, right? How do we solve this issue? Can we simply draw $T_2$ from $\operatorname{Exp}(\alpha)$ and then generate the next increment from $\mathcal N(B_{T_1},T_2)$?
But the what I don't understand is the following: The actual goal was simulation of a path of $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$. Are we still generating such a path, when we follow the scheme above? Don't we alter the distribution of the paths by this exponential time stepping?
Remark: I know that the paper is motivated by situations where $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ could hit some "boundary wall". I'm actually exactly in this situation and so that approach seems promising for my application.

Section 3 of the paper explicitly covers the topic of how $B_T$ can be sampled. In short, your $B_{T_1}$, $B_{T_2}-B_{T_1}, \ldots$ are IID "bilateral exponential RVs" with rate $\sqrt{2\alpha}$, which can be simulated by first simulating an exponential RV with rate $\sqrt{2\alpha}$ and then sampling its signature ($\pm$) with equal probability. The paper also explains how this sampling procedure can be modified in case $B_t$ can hit a wall.

@SangchulLee Yeah, didn't we change the distribution doing so? Is the generated path really a sample path from the Brownian motion?

@SangchulLee See my latest edit. I've tried to clarify my concerns.

I'm not sure that $\frac{\alpha}{2}e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}x}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ could be a density considering  that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\alpha}{2}e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}x} = \infty$, so it can't integrate to $1$.

1. The formula in the paper is correct, and here is a more detailed derivation:
If $T$ is an exponential random variable with rate $\alpha$, and if $B_t$ is the standard Wiener process independent of $T$, then $B_T$ is a symmetric random variable such that, for $x \geq 0$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(|B_T| > x)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{P}(|B_t| > x) \alpha e^{-\alpha t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \biggl( 2 \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-s^2/2t} \, \mathrm{d}s \biggr) \alpha e^{-\alpha t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \alpha \int_{x}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} e^{-s^2/2t} e^{-\alpha t} \, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}
$$
In order to evaluate the inner integral, we substitute $t = u^2$ and invoke Glasser's master theorem:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} e^{-s^2/2t-\alpha t} \, \mathrm{d}t
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\biggl\{ -\frac{s^2}{2u^2}-\alpha u^2 \biggr\} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\biggl\{ -\alpha \biggl( u - \frac{s}{\sqrt{2\alpha} u} \biggr)^2 - \sqrt{2\alpha} s \biggr\} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= 2 e^{- \sqrt{2\alpha} s} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} e^{- \sqrt{2\alpha} s}.
\end{align*}
$$
Plugging this back, we obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(|B_T| > x)
&= \int_{x}^{\infty} \sqrt{2\alpha} e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha} s} \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}
$$
This is precisely the complementary CDF of the exponential distribution with rate $\sqrt{2\alpha}$.
2. Indeed the process obtained by this simulation is no longer a Wiener process. First ignoring the issue of boundary problem, the resulting process $(X_n)$,
$$ X_1 = B_{T_1}, \qquad X_2 = B_{T_2}, \qquad \ldots, $$
with $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tau_i$ for IID $\tau_i \sim \text{Exp}(\alpha)$ (here I might be slightly deviating from OP's notation) is just a random walk with increments $X_i - X_{i-1} = B_{T_i} - B_{T_{i-1}}$ distributed as a Laplace distribution. So, this is not the method of simulating all the values of $(B_t)$ for all $t$, but rather a numerical scheme for approximating the path of $(B_t)$ at chosen timepoints. Of course, the piecewise-linear graph joining points $(0, 0)$, $(T_1, X_1)$, $(T_2, X_2)$, $\ldots$ will converge to the graph of a Wiener process as $\alpha \to \infty$.
Below are comparisons between simulations of $(B_t)$ with exponential timesteps and constant timesteps:

When timesteps are $0.01$ (in average, in the case of exponential timesteps):



When timesteps are $0.0001$ (in average, in the case of exponential timesteps):


But OP also have a point. Here is subtlety that must be considered:

This simulation does not produce "part of a Brownian path". In the paper's simulation scheme, authors do not specify the joint distribution of the timesteps and the increments of the process, i.e., the joint distribution of $(T, B_T)$. Since the conditional distribution of $B_T$ given a value of $T$ is still gaussian, it follows that $T$ and $B_T$ are dependent.
Since the proposed simulation scheme treats $T$ and $B_T$ as if there were independent, which in fact is not, there is no reason to treat the resulting points $(T_i, X_i)$ as part of a Brownian path. This contrasts with the case of fixed timesteps, where the resulting points can indeed be considered as part of a Brownian path.

In the case of boundary condition, a similar remark still applies.

Thank you for your answer! Regarding (1.): I made the same calculations as you and ended up with (my) $(1)$ being the density of $B_T$. So you agree on that? But isn't their (17), which is my $(2)$ and contradiction to that? Due to the absolute value in it. What am I missing?

Regarding (2.): I think you made a mistake. You are considering the process of increments. That's not what we want to do. Instead, you should define $X_1:=B_{T_1}$, $X_2:=B^{(1)}_{T_2}$, and so on.

@0xbadf00d, (1.) My computation actually aligns with the authors. Indeed, for $x>0$, $$f_{B_T}(x)=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathbf{P}(B_T>x)=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{P}(|B_T|>x)=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{1}{2}\int_{x}^{\infty} \sqrt{2\alpha} e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha} s} , \mathrm{d}s=\frac{\sqrt{2\alpha}}{2}e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}x}.$$ For $x<0$, the symmetry implies $f_{B_T}(x)=f_{B_T}(-x)$ and hence the absolute value follows.

@0xbadf00d, (2.) You are right, I mixed up with increments and the process itself. I fixed my answer accordingly! :)

Maybe I should be more explicit. What I calculated is that we actually got $$\operatorname E[f(B_T)]=\sqrt{\frac\alpha2}\int f(x)e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}x};{\rm d}x$$ for every bounded Borel measurable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. Unless you say that this is wrong, shouldn't we immediately infer that $(1)$ is the density with respect to Lebesgue measure? Without the absolute value?

Also worth to mention: The reason why I came up with my question in the first place was Algorithm 1 in this paper. It seems like they are sampling a Brownian path simply by drawing an exponentially distributed step $\tau$ and then from $\mathcal N(X,\tau)$, where $X$ is the previous point on the path. Don't get why that is valid.

@0xbadf00d, You can check that the exponent cannot be $-\sqrt{2\alpha}x$ by plugging $f\equiv 1$ to your proposed equality; in which case the left-hand side becomes $1$ but the right-hand side diverges to $\infty$. As to what kind of mistake you made during computation, I don't know...

And regarding (2.): I know that we cannot simulate a whole path of the Brownian motion on a computer. Since it is continuous in time and hence there are infinitely many points. However, using Euler-Maruyama, we actually generate points which lie on ONE such sample path. But with the exponential time stepping, my worry is that the generated points do NOT lie on a path of a Brownian motion. My worry is that the additional randomness of the time points destroys that property.

Regarding (1.): So, it should be $-\sqrt{2\alpha}|x|$ in the exponent, right? Then I need to check my calculations. Maybe I made a mistake.

(I'd also be interested in your opinion on that Algorithm 1)

@0xbadf00d, As for Algorithm 1, you almost have the answer in your question. It is the combination of two facts: (1) If $\tau$ is independent of $W$, then $(W_{\tau}\mid\tau=t)$, the law of $W_\tau$ conditioned on $\tau=t$, is simply the law of $W_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t)$. (2) $(W_t)$ has strong Markov property as you mentioned in your question. Now recursively apply this facts!

But what's the difference then between the scheme in the paper and Algorithm 1? Both propose exponential time stepping, but Algorithm 1 is clearly simpler and more straightforward. However, my concern regarding points on one actual sample path of a Brownian motion is the same in both algorithms.

And just to be crystal clear what I mean: Any sensible scheme should actually give me points $(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$, where each point $x_i=B_{t_i}(\omega)$ for ONE outcome $\omega\in\Omega$. With Euler-Maruyma, that is actually the case. But with exponential $t_i$ as well???

@0xbadf00d, With Algorithm 1, yes. With the simulation scheme as in the paper by Jansons and Lythe, I doubt as you already suspected. :)

Actually, I still have doubts that this really is the case. And if the parameter of the exponential times is hold constant, it should actually be wrong according to Theorem 1 in this paper. I've described this and a possible solution attempt here. I'd highly appreciate if you could take a look.
